# Number of triples of specific group instances?

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I have found another problem in SPARQLing dbpedia. I am trying to get number of triples for specific group of class instances.

Number of triples of class Politician:

```
 SELECT * WHERE {?s ?p ?o FILTER (?s = dbo:Politician OR ?o = dbo:Politician)}
```

But what about summary number of all triples for a specific group of politicians? For example number of triples of german politician. How is possible to get?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: your query doesn't make sense - I mean, what is this FILTER? And what about the curly braces around the query? First, you have to figure out how your "groups" are determined in the dataset. Next, you have to define the graph pattern with that information and finally, retrieve all triples of those resources and just count them. For classes, the relation would be `rdf:type` (in most cases). For the politician example, it's just `?s rdf:type dbo:Politician .` to get all instances of this class. Then get the triples and do the `count` as I already showed you in your previous question.

Comment: For "German politicians", you have to figure out how this information is encoded in the dataset - you can only query data that exists by the way.

Comment: Doesnt make sense? I think it does. Look what you get, when query `?s rdf:type dbo:Politician` - its 41078 triples. When you query my code with filter (counting) - you get 41091 triples. It is because my code includes result with Politician in subject position and this is what I want. Number of all occurances.

Curly braces around the query is my typing mistake ... sorry.

I know I have to figure it out, how are those information encoded in dataset, but I dont know, how to improve my query to get wanted result.

Comment: your query doesn't reflect what you want. Instances of a type are defined by `rdf:type` predicate, thus, the query should be `select ... {?s rdf:type dbo:Politician}` - and even this would only return the instances but not the number of triples of those instances. It's not clear what the purpose of your query is, but `select count(*) {?s rdf:type dbo:Politician; ?p ?o}` would return the number of all triples of instances of type politician.

Comment: if you want to find out how to distinguish further, e.g. "German politician", the easiest way is obviously to look at the data, look at some of those politicians and check what they have as properties that indicate the nationality

Comment: I know its `dbo:nationality dbr:Germany`, but i still dont know, what query should count all triples form German Politician only...

Comment: Ok, and why can't you then just add the triple pattern `?s dbo:nationality dbr:Germany . ` to the query `select ... {?s rdf:type dbo:Politician}`? I don't understand the problem here, just add more triple patterns to the query if you want to restrict the result

Comment: please check comments below. When I add `?s dbo:nationality dbr:Germany` the result number doesnt seem to be ok. Total number of triples is 41105 and for German Politician 38400? But when I check the string results, is looks ok. This is why Iam so confused ....

Comment: 1. your query does **not** return the number of triples of politicians! It just returns the number of triples that have the class `dbo:Politician` in subject or object position. Nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: 2. what you want is to get all politicians by using `?s rdf:type dbo:Politcian .` and then for those instances all triples, thus, you have to add another triple pattern `?s ?p ?o .` Moreover, you want *the number of triples of German politicians* only, which means add the triple pattern `?s dbo:nationality dbr:Germany`.

Comment: So, the query should be `select count(*) {
?s a dbo:Politician .
?s dbo:nationality dbr:Germany .
?s ?p ?o .
}` and returns `9078` triples as result.

Comment: This makes sense since the number of German politicians in DBpedia is just 82, computed by the query `select count(*) {
?s a dbo:Politician .
?s dbo:nationality dbr:Germany .
}` - so in general, we have ~100 triples about each German politician which sounds ok. Indeed, I'd do some more filtering on the triples of you want to have more the number of "real" properties, e.g. just use triples with predicate from `http://dbpedia.org/ontology/` and/or `http://dbpedia.org/property/` namespace and avoid e.g. `rdfs:label`

Comment: Dear god! Thank you! I finally understand :) Thank you for your attention :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### revised answer

This will [get the count of entities who are described as being Politicians from Germany](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&qtxt=SELECT%20COUNT(*)%20%0D%0A%20%20%7B%20%3Fs%20a%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20dbo%3APolitician%20.%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fs%20dbo%3Anationality%20dbr%3AGermany%20.%20%0D%0A%20%20%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on&run=%20Run%20Query%20) —

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
  { ?s a               dbo:Politician . 
    ?s dbo:nationality dbr:Germany . 
  }
```

— and this will [get the count of all records where those entities who are described as being Politicians from Germany appear as Subject](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&qtxt=SELECT%20COUNT(*)%20%0D%0A%20%20%7B%20%3Fs%20a%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20dbo%3APolitician%20.%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fs%20dbo%3Anationality%20dbr%3AGermany%20.%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fs%20%3Fp%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fo%20.%0D%0A%20%20%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on&run=%20Run%20Query%20) —

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
  { ?s a               dbo:Politician . 
    ?s dbo:nationality dbr:Germany . 
    ?s ?p              ?o .
  }
```

It is possible that you're looking for a bit more info, to [include all records where the entities who are described as being Politicians from Germany appears as either Subject or Object (not just as Subject)](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&qtxt=SELECT%20COUNT(*)%20%0D%0A%20%20%7B%20%7B%20%3Fs%20a%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20dbo%3APolitician%20.%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fs%20dbo%3Anationality%20dbr%3AGermany%20.%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fs%20%3Fp%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fo%20.%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20UNION%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20%3Fo%20a%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20dbo%3APolitician%20.%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fo%20dbo%3Anationality%20dbr%3AGermany%20.%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fs%20%3Fp%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fo%20.%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on&run=%20Run%20Query%20) —

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
  { { ?s a               dbo:Politician . 
      ?s dbo:nationality dbr:Germany . 
      ?s ?p              ?o . 
    }
  UNION
    { ?o a               dbo:Politician . 
      ?o dbo:nationality dbr:Germany . 
      ?s ?p              ?o . 
    }
  }
```

---

#### original answer

I *think* you are currently aiming for [this](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&qtxt=SELECT%20%28%20COUNT%28*%29%20AS%20%3FNumberOfTriples%20%29%20%0D%0AWHERE%0D%0A%20%20%7B%20%7B%20dbo%3APolitician%20%3Fp%20%3Fo%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20UNION%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20%3Fs%20%3Fp%20dbo%3APolitician%20%7D%20%0D%0A%20%20%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=3000000&debug=on&run=%20Run%20Query%20), which counts all triples with `dbo:Politician` as either Subject or Object (which is currently 41105, without timeout), but note that this query doesn't count "entities which are politicians" which is (I think) what you're really after!

```
SELECT ( COUNT ( * ) AS ?NumberOfTriples ) 
WHERE
  { { dbo:Politician ?p ?o }
    UNION
    { ?s ?p dbo:Politician } 
  }
```

If you want to count the number of "entities which are politicians" (i.e., `rdf:type dbo:Politician`) (currently 41078), you need a different query, like [this](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&qtxt=SELECT%20%28%20COUNT%20%28%20DISTINCT%20%3Fs%20%29%20AS%20%3FNumberOfPoliticians%20%29%20%0D%0AWHERE%0D%0A%20%20%7B%20%3Fs%20rdf%3Atype%20dbo%3APolitician%20%7D%20&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=3000000&debug=on&run=%20Run%20Query%20) --

```
SELECT ( COUNT ( DISTINCT ?s ) AS ?NumberOfPoliticians ) 
WHERE
  { ?s rdf:type dbo:Politician }
```

This should be clarified by a look at [the `{ dbo:Politician ?p ?o }` triples](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&qtxt=SELECT%20*%0D%0AWHERE%0D%0A%20%20%7B%20dbo%3APolitician%20%3Fp%20%3Fo%20%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=3000000&debug=on&run=%20Run%20Query%20) --

```
SELECT *
WHERE
  { dbo:Politician ?p ?o }
```

Comment: thank you man! :) BUT i really want to all triples of Politician, not just 'entities which are politician'. Furthermore, I want to have number of triples for only those Politicians, who are from Germany. Is this query correct? 
`SELECT ( COUNT ( * ) AS ?NumberOfTriples ) 
WHERE
  { { dbo:Politician ?p ?o }

    UNION
    { ?s ?p dbo:Politician } 
  
?s dbo:nationality dbr:Germany
}`

The number seems to be large (38400) in fact, that I wanted triples for only German Politician (when all Politician triples has just 41105). But when I check `SELECT ?s ?p ?o`, results seems to be fine

Comment: @Xyz1337 - I've edited my answer.  Please accept it if it covers your desired goal, and consider editing your question to include the details which were provided later via comments.